# After changing of Admob account, my ads are not showing

Tags: android, admob

I uploaded my first App on play store, every thing was going perfectly, Ads were showing in app and revenue was generating also but unfortunately my Admob account was blocked. I sent an email for restoring my admob account but they gave a reason for not restoring same account.
Well I created another Admob account, uploaded my same application over that new Admob account but unfortunately ads are not showing while on test mode ads are showing perfectly.

I am very much upset, It will be so nice of you to guide me on this issue.

Comment: check [this](https://quickappninja.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002693285-Why-aren-t-my-Admob-ads-showing-) post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get upset. You can try Facebook Audience Network.

Here are examples.
http://hackerseve.com/android-integrating-facebook-audience-network-fan/

http://hackerseve.com/android-using-together-admob-and-facebook-audience-network/